# Problemas com hashmap getordefault em java

Tags: java, hashmap

Estou com um problema em hashmap, no JAVA.

Estou tentando criar um programa que leia dados de um carro, salve esses carros em uma ArrayList e organize, pelo fabricante(que seria a key) os carros de sua marca.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Value to user answers
    String resp = "s";
    //New list of Car objects
    List<Car> carros = new ArrayList<>();

    try(Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)){
      while(resp.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){

        //Create a car for every answer
        Car car = new Car();
        String resposta;
        System.out.println("Empresa do carro: ");
        resposta = input.next();
        car.setManufacturerCar(resposta);
        System.out.println("Modelo do carro: ");
        resposta = input.next();
        car.setModelCar(resposta);
        System.out.println("Quantas portas há no carro?");
        resposta = input.next();
        car.setDoorsCar(resposta);
        System.out.println("Marcha manual ou automatica?");
        resposta = input.next();
        car.setGearshift(resposta);

        //Add a car to arraylist
        carros.add(car);

        System.out.println("Deseja continuar?");
        resp = input.next();
      }
    }

    //Map that will be organized
    Map<String, List<Car>> mapCarros = new HashMap<>();

    for(Car c : carros){

      mapCarros.put(c.getManufacturerCar(), carros);

    }

    System.out.println(mapCarros);

}
```

Quando tentei executar, salvando 2 fuscas e um focus, ele salva todos os carros em todos os fabricantes:

```
{VW=[Car{manufacturerCar=VW, modelCar=FUSCA, doorsCar=2, gearshift=MANUAL}, Car{manufacturerCar=VW, modelCar=FUSCA, doorsCar=2, gearshift=MANUAL}, Car{manufacturerCar=FORD, modelCar=FOCUS, doorsCar=4, gearshift=AUTOMATICO}], FORD=[Car{manufacturerCar=VW, modelCar=FUSCA, doorsCar=2, gearshift=MANUAL}, Car{manufacturerCar=VW, modelCar=FUSCA, doorsCar=2, gearshift=MANUAL}, Car{manufacturerCar=FORD, modelCar=FOCUS, doorsCar=4, gearshift=AUTOMATICO}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está salvando a lista `carros` para todas as marcas. Ao invés disso crie uma para cada:

```
for (Car c : carros){
  List<Car> lista;
  if (mapCarros.containsKey(c.getManufacturerCar())) {
    lista = mapCarros.get(c.getManufacturerCar());
  } else {
    lista = new ArrayList<>();
    mapCarros.put(c.getManufacturerCar(), lista);
  }

  lista.add(c);
}
```

Comment: No caso você criou uma lista de objetos Car, compara se a Key é a mesma que o nome do carro, caso seja lista recebe o nome do fabricante, caso não ele cria um ArrayList dentro da lista e adiciona um novo? Confere? De qualquer forma funcionou! Muito obrigado.

Comment: Caso seja recebe a referência da lista, afinal Objetos em `Java` são compartilhados por referência na atribuição. Se não existir cria uma lista nova